# how to call multiple ant targets for foreach

Tags: ant, for-loop, build, ant-contrib

here is what am trying to do, I want to replace name and address from my large number of property files during build, but unfortunately I cant do this, is there a better way of doing this without having to copy paste the foreach twice. can someone help?

```
<target name="replace" >
<foreach target="replace.name,replace.address" param="foreach.file" inheritall="true">
    <path>
                <fileset dir="${build.tmp.dir}/resource">
                <!-- some complicated conditions go here -->
    </path>
</foreach>
</target>

<target name="replace.address">
    <echo>replacing #Address# for ${foreach.file}</echo>
    <replace file="${foreach.file}" token="#Address#" value="${address}" />
</target>

<target name="replace.name">
    <echo>replacing #Name# for ${foreach.file}</echo>
    <replace file="${foreach.file}" token="#Name#" value="${Name}" />
</target>
```

.properties file looks like

```
name=#Name#
address=#Address#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target` of `foreach` is not designed to take more than one target name. It only iterates through the provided list, not the provided targets.

To make the implementation more DRY, you may

- use a `for` loop instead of `foreach` with two `antcall`s;
- use `macrodef` with `for` loop -- `macrodef` can pack several ant xml code into a task-like thing

Actually, for the two targets -- `replace.address` and `replace.name`, are you sure that you want to call them from the commandline?
If not, name them `-replace.address` and `-replace.name` or use `macrodef` -- exposing the iteration body of `foreach` is not a good practice.